# How to display one banner ad every third row in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my English,

I need to display a banner ad from a database every third row in php. Banner ads and rows with the classified are selecting from database. To this moment I create something like this:

**Rows with the classifieds from database:**

```
while(@$row_select_kat = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_select_kat))
        {
            ... //classifieds from database



            if(($row_select_kat['id_ogloszenia']%3)==0)
            {
                $lim = 1;


                echo"<div id=\"rek_poz_a\">";
                modAddsDisplayHelper::wyswietlReklamyPozA();
                echo"</div>";

            }
        }
```

**Selecting banner ads from databes:**

```
public static function wyswietlReklamyPozA()
{
    $baza_danych = &JFactory::getDbo();

    $query_sel_all_banners = "SELECT * FROM juxhv_banners";
    $baza_danych->setQuery($query_sel_all_banners);
    $baza_danych->query();

    $banner_ads = $baza_danych->loadObjectList();

    echo$query_sel_all_banners;
    echo"Liczba x= ".$l_ogloszen;

    foreach($banner_ads as $banner_ad)
    {
        if($banner_ad->state==1)
        {
            echo"$banner_ad->name<br/><img src=\"images/$banner_ad->username/bannerwerbung/$banner_ad->zdjecie\" width=\"434px\" height=\"94px\" />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"No banner";
        }
    }

}
```

When I doing this in that way at every three rows displaying all three banner ads. How can I display only one banner ad every three rows?

URL: [http://www.nachbarhilft.de](http://www.nachbarhilft.de/)

Greetings

Comment: instead $row_select_kat['id_ogloszenia']%3 have (variable) var $iCount =0; and check ($iCount % 3 )== 0  also do not forget to increment before loop ends. it will give more accurate result

Comment: In function wyswietlReklamyPozA() , as you are using for loop, so its echoing all the 3 images whenever this function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use external counter variable which will be incremented on each iteration and depending on its condition you can check modulo condition: Please see the following  updated code.
[code]

```
   $recordCount = 0;        
   while(@$row_select_kat = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_select_kat))
    {

        if(($recordCount%3)==0)
        {

            echo"<div id=\"rek_poz_a\">";
            modAddsDisplayHelper::wyswietlReklamyPozA();
            echo"</div>";

        }

    $recordCount++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($banner_ad->state == 1) {
    echo"$banner_ad->name<br/><img src=\"images/$banner_ad->username/bannerwerbung/$banner_ad->zdjecie\" width=\"434px\" height=\"94px\" />";
    break;
}
```

In this way you only print one banner, but always will be the first with state == 1 in the database.

Maybe is better improve the query:

```
$query_sel_all_banners = "SELECT * FROM juxhv_banners WHERE state = 1 LIMIT 1";
```

That will give you the same result, I think.

I hope it helps